# PHP Best Way to Create Variable from API Content

Tags: php, string, api, parsing

I am very beginner in programmer and I am learning.
I am sorry if my question is too bad.

I want to create variable in php from api content, for example:
This contents is from this URL: `http://example.com/api`

> {"name":"John","age":"20","genre":"male","language":[{"id":"22","name":"english"},{"id":"23","name":"french"}]}

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents("http://example.com/api");
$content = str_replace('"', "", $content);
$content = str_replace(":", "=", $content);
$content = str_replace(",", "&", $content);
parse_str($content);
echo $name; //John
echo $age; //20
echo $genre; //male
echo $language //[{id <======== here is my problem
?>
```

My problem is when I am getting an array like "language", how to fix it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your API content is a JSON string: use [`json_decode($content)`](http://www.php.net/json_decode) to directly convert it into php variables/objects.

Comment: @fusion3k thanks, i have to learn more.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_decode()` will help you to convert the string data to something more accessible:

```
<?php
// Instead of your fetched data we use static example data in this script
//$content = file_get_contents("http://example.com/api");
$content = '{"name":"John","age":"20","genre":"male","language":[{"id":"22","name":"english"},{"id":"23","name":"french"}]}';

// Convert json data to object
$data = json_decode($content);

// access object properties by using "->" operator
echo $data->name;
echo $data->age;
echo $data->genre;

// language is an array of objects, so let's look at each language object...
foreach($data->language as $lang) {
  // ... and extract data using "->" again
  echo $lang->id;
  echo $lang->name;
}
```

A live example of this code can be found at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6df679c3faa8fff43308a34fb80b2eeb0ccfe47c

Answer (score 2):

U can use the http://www.php.net/json_decode in two ways :

This is **object** oriented :

```
$str = '{"name":"John","age":"20","genre":"male","language":[{"id":"22","name":"english"},{"id":"23","name":"french"}]}';
$json = json_decode($str);

echo 'name: ' . $json->{'name'} .'<br>';
echo 'age: ' . $json->{'age'} .'<br>';
echo 'genre: ' . $json->{'genre'} . '<br>';

foreach($json->{'language'} as $data){
    echo 'id: ' . $data->{'id'} . '<br>';
    echo 'name: ' . $data->{'name'} . '<br>';
}
```

As an **associative** array :

```
$json = json_decode($str, true);

echo 'name: ' . $json['name'] .'<br>';
echo 'age: ' . $json['age'] .'<br>';
echo 'genre: ' . $json['genre'] . '<br>';

foreach($json['language'] as $data){
    echo 'id: ' . $data['id'] . '<br>';
    echo 'name: ' . $data['name'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: This is the much preferred answer (in *my* opinion), nice breakdown of both!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @fusionK, the response from the api request is a json string so convert to an object ( or array if preferred ) using `json_decode` ( `json_decode( $data,true )` for an array )

Once it is decoded it is straightforward to access the properties of the object.

```
<?php
    /* capture and decode response from api - creates an object */
    $content = json_decode( file_get_contents("http://example.com/api") );
    /* using object notation to access properties */
    echo $content->name.' '.$content->age.' '.$content->genre;

    /* for the language which is an array of objects */
    $lang=$content->language;
    foreach( $lang as $language ){
        $obj=(object)$language;
        echo $obj->id.' '.$obj->name;
    }
?>
```